# Different CSP based on login state and browser?

Tags: content-security-policy

Is it a valid approach to have:

1. different CSPs for logged-in vs anonymous users?
2. different CSPs for different "reported" browsers?

Background to this question is that I'd like to use `nonce` and `strict-dynamic` in the `script-src` for browsers that support it, but don't find a good way to make it backward compatible. So I thought of basing it on the user agent, so that at least the newer browsers use that, and older ones would fall back to `unsafe-inline` and hashes.

*Disclosure: I have already posted this question in [Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/307218/is-it-a-valid-approach-to-have-a-different-csp-based-on-login-state-and-browser).*

Answer (score 0):

[Google's strict CSP](https://csp.withgoogle.com/docs/strict-csp.html) works exactly in browsers backward compatibility mode.
You can take it as base and change `http: https:` part to a whitelist of your real host-sources to provide much security for Safari users.

A more detailed answer is in your [topic on Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/307218/is-it-a-valid-approach-to-have-a-different-csp-based-on-login-state-and-browser/307248#307248), as you provided more specific data there.